# How to add 'Add More' button to a set of dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, html-select

when the 1st (destination) and 2nd (attraction or activity) dropdown lists are selected the options the 3rd drop down list shows the available activities or attractions dynamically.

here is the demo : http://codepen.io/foolishcoder7721/pen/jWYOxm

my mark up:

```
<div class="multi-field-wrapper">
  <button type="button" class="add-field">Add Destination</button>        
  <div class="multi-fields">
    <div class="multi-field">
        <select class="text-one" name="destination[]">
            <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
            <option value="colombo">Colombo</option>
        </select>
        <br />

        <select class="text-two" name="attraction_or_activity[]">
            <option value="attraction_or_activity">Select the attractions or activities</option>
            <option value="attraction">Attraction</option>
            <option value="activity">Activity</option>
        </select>


        <select id="populated_attr_or_activity" name="attraction_or_activity_selected[]">
            <!-- here I ahve to populate the ARRAYS as option -->
            <option value="available_attr_act">Available attractions / activities</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery for that:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".text-two").change(function() { // when the attraction_OR_activity dropdown is selected
    $('#populated_attr_or_activity').html(''); // emptying the selections of 3rd dropdown list if there was any selections were made before.

        /* saving selected values in variables */
        var selected_destination = $('.text-one :selected').val();
        var selected_attraction_or_activity = $('.text-two :selected').val();

        colombo_attractions = new Array("Ganga Ramaya","National Art Gallery","Galle Face Green","Arcade Indepentent Square");
        colombo_activities = new Array("City Walk 2016","Traditional Dance Competition 2016","Local Spicy food");

        if ( selected_destination == 'colombo' && selected_attraction_or_activity == 'attraction') {
            colombo_attractions.forEach(function(t) { 
                $('#populated_attr_or_activity').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
            });
        }

        if ( selected_destination == 'colombo' && selected_attraction_or_activity == 'activity') {
            colombo_activities.forEach(function(t) { 
                $('#populated_attr_or_activity').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

That part works perfectly.

Now I want to a add more (add destination) button to create another set same dropdown lists. so guests can select more than one attractions and the activity.
For that I've added following jQuery part to the script.

```
<script>
    /* ADD DESTINATION */
    $('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
        var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
        var x = 1;
        $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
            x++;
                $($wrapper).append('<div class="multi-field"><select class="text-one'+x+'" name="destination[]"><option selected value="base">Please Select</option><option value="colombo">Colombo</option><option value="kandy">Kandy</option><option value="anuradhapura">Anuradhapura</option></select><br/><select class="text-two'+x+'" name="attraction_or_activity[]"><option value="attraction_or_activity">Select the attractions or activities</option><option value="attraction">Attraction</option><option value="activity">Activity</option></select><select id="populated_attr_or_activity'+x+'" name="attraction_or_activity_selected[]"><option value="available_attr_act">Available attractions / activities</option></select><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
        });

        $($wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

I am able to get a set of same dropdown list when I click the `<button type="button" class="add-field">Add Destination</button>`
Remove also works fine.
You can check the demo : http://codepen.io/foolishcoder7721/pen/jWYOxm

but the issue is I am unable load the 'availble attraction/activities' on the 2nd or 3rd set of drop down list.

I think it's because of same variable NAME I am using in `selected_destination` and `selected_attraction_or_activity`.

`var selected_attraction_or_activity+x` gives me error.

how can make it work?

What I have to change to generate dynamic variables and arrays to load the available attractions / activities in 3rd dropdown in the set of 2nd and 3rd dynamically generated dropdown list according to the options selected?

Comment: In such a case, you should perhaps not use ids or names to select elements to begin with – but rather navigate between elements by their relationship in the DOM. https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Comment: Try modifying your code as below,
https://jsfiddle.net/2am152en/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your code as below,

HTML:

```
<div class="multi-field-wrapper">
      <button type="button" class="add-field">Add Destination</button>        
      <div class="multi-fields">
        <div class="multi-field">
            <select class="text-one" name="destination[]">
                <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
                <option value="colombo">Colombo</option>
            </select>
            <br />

            <select class="text-two" name="attraction_or_activity[]">
                <option value="attraction_or_activity">Select the attractions or activities</option>
                <option value="attraction">Attraction</option>
                <option value="activity">Activity</option>
            </select>
            <!--input id="attr_acti_btn" type="button" value="Click to Show!" /-->

            <select class="populated_attr_or_activity" name="attraction_or_activity_selected[]">
                <!-- here I ahve to populate the ARRAYS as option -->
                <option value="available_attr_act">Available attractions / activities</option>
            </select>
        </div>
            <br/>
            <!--div id="myDiv"></div>
            <div id="attr_or_act_div"></div>

          <!--a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a-->

    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(document).on('change', '.text-two', function () { // when the attraction_OR_activity dropdown is selected
    var destination = $(this).parents('.multi-field');
    $(destination).find('.populated_attr_or_activity').html(''); // emptying the selections of 3rd dropdown list if there was any selections were made before.

    /* saving selected values in variables */
    var selected_destination = $(destination).find('.text-one :selected').val();
    var selected_attraction_or_activity = $(destination).find('.text-two :selected').val();

    colombo_attractions = new Array("Ganga Ramaya", "National Art Gallery", "Galle Face Green", "Arcade Indepentent Square");
    colombo_activities = new Array("City Walk 2016", "Traditional Dance Competition 2016", "Local Spicy food");

    if (selected_destination == 'colombo' && selected_attraction_or_activity == 'attraction') {
        colombo_attractions.forEach(function (t) {
            $(destination).find('.populated_attr_or_activity').append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
        });
    }

    if (selected_destination == 'colombo' && selected_attraction_or_activity == 'activity') {
        colombo_activities.forEach(function (t) {
            $(destination).find('.populated_attr_or_activity').append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
        });
    }


});

/* ADD DESTINATION */
$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function () {
    var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
    var x = 1;
    $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function (e) {
        x++;
        $($wrapper).append('<div class="multi-field"><select class="text-one" name="destination[]"><option selected value="base">Please Select</option><option value="colombo">Colombo</option><option value="kandy">Kandy</option><option value="anuradhapura">Anuradhapura</option></select><br/><select class="text-two" name="attraction_or_activity[]"><option value="attraction_or_activity">Select the attractions or activities</option><option value="attraction">Attraction</option><option value="activity">Activity</option></select><select class="populated_attr_or_activity" name="attraction_or_activity_selected[]"><option value="available_attr_act">Available attractions / activities</option></select><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
    });

    $($wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

});

https://jsfiddle.net/2am152en/

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <div id='main'>
        Number: <input type="text" class="nums"/><br/>
    </div>
    <button id="more">Add More</button>
    <button id="result">Resut</button>
    <p><b>Total:</b>0</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('#more').on('click',function(e){
                var textFied = 'Number: <input type="text" class="nums"/><br/>';
                $('#main').append(textFied);
            });

            $('#result').on('click',function(e){
                var nums = $('.nums'),total = 0;
                $(nums).each(function(index, el) {
                   total+=$(el).val()*1;   
               });
                $('p').html('<b>Total:</b>'+total);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/rampukar/5n1j3ehr/

**Output:**
[image]